# Dynamically Adjust Height of TabBarView with ListView Inside in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, mobile-development

I'm working on a Flutter project where I have a ListView inside a TabBarView. I want the TabBarView to dynamically adjust its height based on the content of the ListView. However, when I use Expanded or Flexible to achieve this, the entire page disappears, and I encounter an error indicating that the Expanded widget is unbounded.

fulters_filters.dart:

```
class _ProductFiltersState extends State<ProductFilters>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController filterTabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    filterTabController = TabController(
      length: 7,
      vsync: this,
      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 32, bottom: 18),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // Set mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min

        children: [
          // Filters where can user search for items
          filtersTab(context),
          SizedBox(
            height: 18,
          ),
          // title : Newset Product of the week
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
            child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  'News Labase of The week',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 12,
          ),
          // items that will be displayed
          SizedBox(
            height: 310,
            child: productFiltersView(),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 24 * 1.618,
          ),
          // title : Newset Product of the week
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
            child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  'Most item selling',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 12,
          ),
          // items that will be displayed
          SizedBox(
            height: 305,
            child: topProductFiltersView(),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 24 * 1.618,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  TabBarView productFiltersView() {
    return TabBarView(
      controller: filterTabController,
      children: [
        PackSeriesProducts(), // Listview
        PackSeriesProducts(),
        PackSeriesProducts(),
        PackSeriesProducts(),
        PackSeriesProducts(),
        PackSeriesProducts(),
        PackSeriesProducts()
      ],
    );
  }

  TabBarView topProductFiltersView() {
    return TabBarView(controller: filterTabController, children: [
      TopProductSelling(),
      TopProductSelling(),
      TopProductSelling(),
      TopProductSelling(),
      TopProductSelling(),
      TopProductSelling(),
      TopProductSelling()
    ]);
  }

  TabBar filtersTab(BuildContext context) {
    return TabBar(
      isScrollable: true,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
      controller: filterTabController,
      indicator: ShapeDecoration(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
        ),
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiary,
      ),
      unselectedLabelColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiary,
      tabs: [
        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
            width: 85,
            child: Tab(
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Filter $i', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Listview:packseries.dart:

```
class _PackSeriesProductsState extends State<PackSeriesProducts> {
  PageController productsPackOfTheWeek = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: 5,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: index == 0 ? 16 : 4,
          right: index == 4 ? 16 : 4,
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 180,
              height: 240,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Raouaa Shop',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 3),
                Text(
                  'Darb Taam barima...',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                  softWrap: true,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 8),
                Text(
                  '80% discount',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.greenAccent),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

home_screen.dart:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          unselectedItemColor: Color.fromARGB(167, 158, 158, 158),
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
          iconSize: 32.0,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                ),
                label: 'Home'),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.shopping_bag_rounded,
                ),
                label: 'market'),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.qr_code_rounded,
                ),
                label: 'Qr Code'),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.favorite_rounded,
                ),
                label: 'Profile'),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.person_2_rounded,
                ),
                label: 'Profile'),
          ]),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              UserInfoHeader(
                username: 'Med Khalil',
                notificationOn: true,
                userLocation: 'Meknes lahdim babrha',
              ),
              SearchEngine(),
              UserFollowingSellers(),
              AdsAndDiscounts(),
              Prodcuts(),
              CompaniesAndManufactur(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

I've tried using Expanded and Flexible around the ListView, but it results in an error. How can I dynamically adjust the height of the TabBarView based on the content of the ListView without encountering this issue?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!